# xhr request response should not pick from disk cache rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Chrome does not hit server after clicking to button to fetch the data. It just fetches from `cache disk`. If I clear the cache then only request goes to the server but from next click same thing happens, It starts fetching data from the cache.

After button click, I am rendering the partial using remote: true.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following header to your response :

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

This will instruct the browser to turn off caching for this request endpoint.

Another workaround from the client side - Add a unique parameter to the endpoint. A way to generate unique parameter is to use the current timestamp. For example:

```
url += '?timestamp=' + Date.now()
```

Comment: Can I do something in my controller? because the header is written in the different file and that can affect other pages as well. So I Just want my page should not get a cache.